# Create Fantasy Map

Tags: openstreetmap, google-maps, web-mapping, software-recommendations, mapping

I'm currently looking to create a Fantasy map and share it with my friends. We have the map designed already in Flash to certain degrees of detail and able to export as a vector.

We'd like it to be usable as something like Google Maps, able to zoom in to show greater levels of details. Searching for locations... etc. would be an added bonus.

We've been looking into Leaflet and OpenStreetMap, but seem to be a little confused and overwhelmed. Can anyone suggest some simple to use software where we may be able to import our vectors and build upon them? Online or offline.

Comment: Note that the OpenStreetMap project is about collection real-world data and not designed to create fantasy maps in the first place. Of course it is possible to use the various tools around it (the database, the editors for adding/changing data, the geocoder Nominatim for searching locations, the renderer Mapnik for drawing maps, and of course Leaflet or OpenLayers for viewing the rendered map in your browser) in order to create your own fantasy map. But the setup is not easy because, yeah, it is not primarily designed for creating your own fantasy map.

Comment: Like this? http://maps.marlam.in/ http://wyrimaps.net/wow

Comment: Yes that's pretty much exactly what we'd like to do, although I imagine without the resources and skills it wouldn't be to that level.

Comment: Some tutorials: [One using Google](http://blog.mikecouturier.com/2011/07/create-zoomable-images-using-google.html) and [another using Leaflet](http://build-failed.blogspot.com/2012/11/zoomable-image-with-leaflet.html), both work quite nicely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CartoDB (https://cartodb.com/ ) is quite good for this, or you can convert your vector to the KML format and open it in Google Earth.

Answer (score 3):

so the fundamental question to me is: Do you want to create a real fantasy (here: **fictional**) **map** that has nothing to do with reality or create just a **fantasy like map style**?

If the **first one** is what you want, you can make use of existing OSM technologies (editors, renderers, ...) or general free GIS technology (QGIS, OpenJUMP, ...) to create and visualize such a map. But please pay attention that you don't upload your stuff to the OSM DB as it doesn't reflect the reality and might destroy the work of others! So you download an OSM area with JOSM editor, erase everything and work local with this .osm file that now contains all your fantasy world.

If you just want to present/recycle your **existing drawings**, you need to convert them to a raster image like .PNG and make use of a [webmap toolkit](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Frameworks#Webmaps) to present it in your browser. As everything is fictional, you don't need/have a coordinate system or map projection or you just use the defaults like for Google Maps. With OpenLayers, it might work [like this](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/image-layer.html).

For the **second one**, you might play with existing [(offline) renderers](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering) like Tilemill or Maperitive. There are also some nice artistic/fantasy map styles that might already fit for you:

- http://maps.stamen.com/#watercolor
- http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Maps#Art